# ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [4553], [2], [0], [], [], [], [], []

Tags: oracle10g

I use `oracle` 10g in my company. When I write

```
create table master as(select * from masterfile)
```

in toad, it was showing notification like this

> ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [4553], [2], [0], [], [], [], [], []

What must I do?

Comment: [What have you tried? What have you googled? Have you tried to solve it on your own?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I've tried like in this post "https://community.oracle.com/thread/846627?start=0&tstart=0" but nothing happen.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO! Please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) post for how to ask better questions, which will help people give you better answers.

Comment: A starting point to any ORA-600 errors should always be run through ORA-600/ORA-7445/ORA-700 Error Look-up Tool (Doc ID 153788.1): go out to https://support.oracle.com and search for 153788.1 to access this utility (which, I believe can be accessed and used without an Oracle support contract).